# Export DataGrid WPF MVVMLight C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have a Datagrid full of datas. Behind I have a export button.
How can get all the data from the datagrid? (Command parameter?)

My button is binded to an `ICommand` who refers to a method. The method call the class to create the pdf, but I don't know how am I suppose to get the grid in parameter of this method. (Or something else that I can use)

My goal is to export all the datagrid in a PDF file.

Comment: Have you tried solving this on your own? You should try and post some code so that we can help you. Nobody is going to write all of the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see parameters of that method class for printing pdf but here is explanation without it:

With foreach loop you can get row by row from dataGridView and then from there you can get this:

```
//This is repeating for every row in datagridview
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    // gives you value of specified cell at column
    // pdfMethod is method you call and inside i set it like one argument
    pdfMethod(row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value);

   //or you can make method that in which you will input whole row
   pdfMethod(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your help.

My issue was that my DataGrid was an "System.Windows.Forms" instead of "System.Windows.Controls".
I made a mistake in my usings.

Thx guys !